# Where to find Beta-Testers

Tags: manual-testing, mobile

New to the site. Please let me know if this question is out of the scope of this forum, and if there is a better place to post it.

I have developed many applications both in a production environment and for personal use. In the production environment, we have dedicated software analysts, testers, and frameworks/procedures to self-test the code. However, with personal development there are only so many devices/platforms I can test my programs with, and only so much time in the world. I'd love to crowd source the testing, but my few attempts (namely this one: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-betatesters/1SWl_v40v5I/5q3RPuLQPzQJ) has failed miserably.

Can you recommend any communities that might be of service?

PS- Please do not mistake this post as a shameless plug of my app. I am genuinely interested in finding/developing a community dedicated to beta-testing. I am not here only for self-service.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want people who will beta test your app or are you looking for testers who will test your app in a beta cycle? (The difference being skill level)

Comment: I'm a big believer in the power of the masses. I'd rather have more, inexperienced testers than a few pros. Like developing any product, you need experts to vet out the major issues, but focus groups also provide invaluable information. So to answer your question, yes  :P

Comment: Contact me... My team will help you with it... Write to me at milinpatel17@gmail.com

Answer (score 5):

**Applause**

You could try [Applausse](http://www.applause.com/) the testing services based on their tester network from [UTest](http://www.utest.com/), I have done some cross-browser and mobile app testing for them.

They offer scripted testcases and exploratory sessions where you pay per found issue.

**Amazon Mechanical Turk**

With [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/) you can define small work loads. Like install and do some action, give some feedback. I am not sure you can force people to use certainly mobile devices, but I think it should be possible.

Comment: Applause/UTest can be good for business but not for private purposes, 'cause the prices are skihigh.

Comment: Hiring people to-do work will cost money, the OP did not state it had to be free. If your pet project has potential and you want to make sure it works, investing a bit might be good idea. Since you only get one chance on a first impression.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any free ones, but there are a number of services around that do exactly what you're after. Plus, they range from system or system integration testing to beta or user acceptance testing - so it really depends on your requirements.

Check out [Bug Wolf](https://bugwolf.com/), [99 tests](https://99tests.com/) and [Bug Finders](https://thebugfinder.com/en/) to see if they suit your needs. Otherwise, Googling something along the lines of "*crowd sourced testing*" or something more specific like "*crowd sourced beta testing*" - you'll definitely find something.

Hope this helps!

**Note:** I don't work for any of the companies listed but have looked at them previously for similar reasons.

Comment: @Paramjeet, I appreciate you updating my answer with working links... but do you work for Qantily?

Answer (score 3):

Why not check us out! We have 17 k beta testers in our community and they together own 470 different devices. You can do both private and public tests and also choose if you would like to pay the testers or if it's a free test. Have a look and see if our platform could work for you. https://betafamily.com/

Comment: Not a huge user base, but otherwise just what I am looking for! I signed up and created a test, and even joined a few myself. Great platform.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two solutions for this kind of situation:

**Free solution:**

- Websites such as [Betabound](https://www.betabound.com/).

They collect and organize a wide variety of beta testing opportunities from all over the world and post them for free.

You can submit your project there for free.

- Facebook groups for *Beta testers*

**Paid solution:**

There are also  companies that are providing crowd testing solutions, sometimes for free if that's an non-profit project:

They tend to be very expensive and don't have fixed pricing, so be prepared.

- http://www.utest.com/ | http://www.applause.com/
- http://whatusersdo.com/
- http://trymyui.com/
- http://www.testbirds.com/
- http://www.usertesting.com/
- https://crowdsourcedtesting.com/
- https://mycrowd.com/
- https://test.io/
- https://usabilityhub.com/
- https://globalapptesting.com/
- https://www.bugfinders.com/
- https://we-are-testers.com/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a new platform called http://rainforestqa.com. It's a new approach to crowdtesting where you can arrange testers with different web/mobile environments.

There is also a number of free test sessions you can execute, so you'll be able to evaluate the tool without needing to pay upfront

Comment: Viktor, RainforestQA is an automation service for regression, not a crowd testing service for beta. Also, I'm not sure you can say Applause and uTest are expensive when their cheapest plan is $500 a month? Personally, that sounds like a lot of money. Do you work for them?

Answer (score 1):

You can try from freelancing sites. You will get lot of experienced testers there. You will have diff. testing experts there. You can choose best one according to your need and budget.

Utest community is also good solution. That is also collection of good testers.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at those below, I already worked as a tester for [test.io](https://test.io/de/). There were interesting tests from major companies like [immowelt.de](http://www.immowelt.de/) and [Blacklane](https://www.blacklane.com/en).

- [test.io](https://test.io/de/)
- [Testbirds](http://www.testbirds.com/)
- [rapidusertests.com](http://rapidusertests.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several beta testing providers. You can choose the one which fits your needs. If you want high quality testing with reliable results, one good resource http://qualitrix.com/ . Another good option is https://www.passbrains.com/.

Comment: Please do not quote from websites without attribution. I've edited your post to make it clear your information about Qualitrix is quoted from their site.

Answer (score 0):

Some projects require crowdsourcing testing, while some outsourcing, I'd recommend you to use both of them! Some companies suggest software testing for free, like [QAwerk](https://qawerk.com/) in terms of their weekly bug crawls. I think that independent testing of your product would be an excellent experience for you!